# Add values from multiple dictionaries in firebase into an Int

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to store the amount of views every video in my app has been seen. What I want to is to gather all views from from one users all videos and display the total number of views. However I'm having problems fetching down the data and putting all the dictionary values together into a Int/String!

Ive tried many different solutions so far, but still I get all the different values in like array / values of the dictionary instead of everything added into one value

This is my code for getting all the videoviews of a specific user, no problems with this so far. When I print "intConvert" I get like all the views in different rows.

---

```
      let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoviews").child(stringUid)
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            let numbOfViews = dictionary["views"] as! String
            let intConvert = Int(numbOfViews)!
            let ArrayViews = [intConvert]
```

---

This is my database structure:

```
   **videoviews**
        -Lb52VxrEqdSRGljJdP7
                          views: "25"

        -Lb53ARq_lOHEbTruW8s
                          views: "273"

        -Lb53A_cEyX3CYc4mKYn
                          views: "38"
```

---

EDIT: If I do print(dictionary), the dictionary from "if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Anyobject] looks like this:

```
      ["views": 642]
      ["views": 660]
      ["views": 628]
      ["views": 630]
      ["views": 615]
      ["views": 3]
      ["views": 0]
      ["views": 2]
      ["views": 1]
```

---

Edit: (I was confused and forgot to add the bracelets, sorry for that.)
when I do I "print(dictionary.values) the console looks like this (the key values from different dictionaries):

```
  [642]
  [660]
  [628]
  [630]
  [615]
   [3]
   [0]
   [2]
   [1]
```

I then tried to put this together in a loop like this:

---

```
       var bLoader = 0.0
            for hejArray in 0...ArreyViews.count-1{
                bLoader += Double(Arrej[hejArray])
            }
```

---

But when I print "bLoader" I still get all the views for every video in different rows instead of gathered in one value.

So what do I need to do put together all the values from different dictionaries in Firebase into one Variable?

I appreciate all help I can get with this, I can imagine it shouldn't be too hard but that im missing out on something.

**EDIT** /// I finally found the problem. the "StringUid" that I passed in have different amount of values and therefore the whole function would be called for 9 times if the videos of the user had the amount of 9. The solution that finally worked looked like this:

Global Array declaration:

```
              var myArray = [String]()
```

Inside the function:

```
       if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let numbOfViews = dictionary["views"] as! String
            let intConvert = Int(numbOfViews)!
            self.myArray.append(numbOfViews)
            let intArray = self.myArray.map { Int($0)!} 
            let total = intArray.reduce(0, +)
            self.totalViewsShower2.text = String(total)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If you can directly print the values from your dictionary like that then the solution might be as easy as

```
let total = dictionary.values.reduce(0, +)
```

or if values are strings you need to convert them to Int

```
let total = dictionary.values.reduce(0) {sum, value -> Int in return sum + (Int(value) ?? 0)}
```

If on the other hand they values are string but defined as Any you need an extra cast

```
let total2 = dictionary2.values.reduce(0) {sum, value -> Int in
    if let str = value as? String {
        return sum + (Int(str) ?? 0)
    }
    return 0
}
```

I am not exactly sure what your dictionary contains but I assumed something like this

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["views": ["1", "2", "3"]]
```

Then you can cast the value for the "views" key to a String array and then use `reduce` on that array to get the sum

```
let array = dictionary["views"] as! [String]
let total = array.reduce(0) {sum, value -> Int in return sum + (Int(value) ?? 0)}
```

Comment: Hi Joakim, thank you for your answer. I tried this but when I declare the array like that the app crashes. I updated my answer with how the console looks and also the database structure :)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I was clumsy, when I print (dictionary.values) I forgot to add the [ ] in my post.. However, you are right, they are defined as Anyobject and need to be casted to String -> Int If I understand correctly. I tried your answer, when I print total2 I get the values like 642, 660... but still in different rows. It still seems like every dictionary is getting converted by itself instead of put together into one value!

Comment: Your code would have worked from start if I had realized that the function were called as many times as the amount of StringUids. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to your Database structure which looks something like this

```
{
    "videoviews": {
        "Lb52VxrEqdSRGljJdP7": {
            "views": "25"
        },
        "Lb53ARq_lOHEbTruW8s": {
            "views": "273"
        },
        "Lb53A_cEyX3CYc4mKYn": {
            "views": "38"
        }
    }
}
```

```
 let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoviews").child(stringUid)
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let viewsArray = dictionary.values
                            .compactMap { $0 as? [String: String] }
                            .compactMap { Int($0["views"] ?? "") }

            let totalViews = viewsArray.reduce(0, +)
        }
})
```

Comment: Here is documentation for `compactMap`, for your reference:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap

Comment: Thank you for your your answer. I am kind of unfamiliar compactMap so far so I might be doing something wrong. when I put in your code the compiler tells me to change the "" in the 2nd compact map to an Int to let me run the code. When I then print the totalViews I get the values as 0 and in different rows. If I understand firebase correctly, it has to be in this order. Anyobject -> String -> Int. Maybe with some code change above works! :)

Comment: @Wurzel  I have updated the code little bit, rather than type casting directly to `[String: Int]` now changed to `[String: String]`.
I hope this should work based on the information provided.

Comment: Hi again! Thanks, I tried your edited code. When I print the totalViews I still get 0 in differents row though. I updated my post with how print(dictionary) and print(dictionary.values) looks in the console. Could it have to do something with looks for ["views"] when we already look at the value and not the key maybe?

Comment: `let viewsArray = dictionary.values
                            .compactMap { $0 as? [String: AnyObject] }
                            .compactMap { ($0["views"] as NSNumber).intValue }`

Can you try this? I think the issue is with type conversion.

Comment: I tried this and it returned 0 9 times(the test user has 9 videos) in different rows. The .child(strindUid) contains all of the videoIds which gets picked from a Didselectrow where I declare my userClass. Could this have anything to do with this? Even if the values aren't correct. It seems like whatever I do all the "views" gets printed in different rows instead of put into one row and one value

Comment: I also tried to only use this one .compactMap { $0 as? [String: AnyObject] } and then also only this one .compactMap { $0 as? [String: String] } and then do print(viewsArray). this return 0. Since dictionary.values is only the numbers and not the key "views" it might not be finding any value with this code?

Comment: Edit: I finally found the solution (The problem was that the functions was being called as many times as the amount of StringUids. That would maybe be obvious but hey im a beginner (: ). Thanks however for your help and new knowledge in compactMap!